# Does the user_register change in multisite?

Tags: user-registration

I've created a function that automatically creates a new post for people when they register. It works great on a standard site but in multisite it stops working. I've spent hours trying to debug it. Is there a better hook to use than `user_register` in multisite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the action hook [**`wpmu_new_user`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/ms-functions.php#L896).

```
/*
 * Create a user.
 *
 * This function runs when a user self-registers as well as when
 * a Super Admin creates a new user. Hook to 'wpmu_new_user' for events
 * that should affect all new users, but only on Multisite (otherwise
 * use 'user_register').
```